# UID doesn't show out of constructor

Tags: authentication, angular, firebase, angularfire

I have some problems trying to get the uid out of my constructor. When i run this code the uid shows perfectly in the Test 1 log. However the Test2 log shows its undefined. Does the uid deletes himself when the constructor closes?

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {AngularFire, FirebaseObjectObservable, FirebaseListObservable} from 'angularfire2';

@Component({
  selector: 'dashboard',
  templateUrl: 'dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.css']
})
export class DashboardComponent {
  userid:string;
  users:FirebaseListObservable<any[]>;
  constructor(public af: AngularFire) {
    this.af.auth.subscribe(auth => {
      console.log(auth.uid);
      this.userid = auth.uid;
      console.log("Test 1 "+ this.userid);
    });
    console.log("Test2 "+ this.userid);
  }
}
```

this is my output in my console

```
Angular 2 is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode.
dashboard.component.ts:18 Test2 undefined
dashboard.component.ts:14 CgTltJ1h2TUFS5teoACCxoPHP1g1
dashboard.component.ts:16 Test 1 CgTltJ1h2TUFS5teoACCxoPHP1g1
```

My second question is how can i get the uid out of my constructor? Cause i need it to get some othre data from the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `console.log("Test2...")` is executed the value is not yet available

When the data arrives from the server the function passed to `subscribe()`

```
    auth => {
      console.log(auth.uid);
      this.userid = auth.uid;
      console.log("Test 1 "+ this.userid);
    }
```

is called, only then the data becomes available and only within that function, `console.log("Test2 ...")` was executed a looong time before that

```
export class DashboardComponent {
  userid:string;
  users:FirebaseListObservable<any[]>;
  constructor(public af: AngularFire) {
    this.af.auth.subscribe(auth => {
      console.log(auth.uid);
      this.userid = auth.uid;
      console.log("Test 1 "+ this.userid);
    });
    console.log("Test2 "+ this.userid);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that answer, it clears a lot. But is there any solution how i can get the data outside my constructor?

Comment: You can get it outside the constructor just fine. Just assign it to a property (`this.userid = auth.uid;` does this). The question should be more like, "**when** can I access it outside the constructor".

Comment: It depends on what you exactly try to accomplish. If you want to use it in template binding `[xxx]="auth?.id"` then just use the additional `?` to prevent errors when the value is not yet available. If you want to use it in code, then call the code from within the callback you pass to `subscribe(...)`.

Comment: So wait could you right down what i would type to get it outside the constructor?

Comment: Your code already contains that (`this.userid = auth.uid;`). You can't have it where `console.log("Test2 ...")` is called because this is executed before the call to Firebase was even made.

Comment: Oke i get that. That you explained in your first answer but how can i call it afther firabase is made?

Comment: Add the code where `console.log("Test 1 ...)` is. You can call methods of your class (or others) from there.

Comment: Aight i get it now thanks a lot. So i just have to get every call in my constructor method & not outside the method. So for instance i need to check on a othre db at uid i can just make the call for  the new db in the constructor as well & check on the uid i got from the user there

Comment: Exactly, this code is called by `Observable` when the response arrives, and everything within it has the response available and you can pass it along from there. You should have a closer looks at observables and promises, they are quite powerful with lots of powerful operators http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/01/06/taking-advantage-of-observables-in-angular2.html

Comment: Aight i will Thanks a lot Gunter you really helped me a lot!!